# Azure Portal Login disabled after Azure AD added

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory

So the situation is this, probably about 18 months ago, I developed a couple app services and deployed to Azure.  At the exact same time our in house SA attempted to move our on premise AD into an Azure AD so that was my azure AD account was what I used to provision all my services, data bases etc.  For what ever I don't understand, our SA decided to roll everything back a couple weeks later, my account still worked so thought nothing of it.
Now, our SA has re-implemented the Azure AD and I can longer get into my Azure Portal.
I get the message "The Username may be incorrect.  Make sire you typed it correctly.  Otherwise contact your Admin"  I've tried:

1. Contacting my Admin, "I don't know" was his answer.
2. Tried the account recovery, selecting the option Work or School Account.  Enter my id and get the response "The user ID you entered does not exist. Please check that you have typed your user ID correctly"
3. Tried the account recovery, selecting Personal Account.  Enter my id and get "Try entering your Microsoft account again. We don't recognize this one."
4. Tried to create a support ticket, but seems I need to log in to create a ticket, which gets me back to the start.

Any body have any ideas, it appears my Microsoft account weather it is a work one or a personal is dead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem sorted.  Turns out that when our SA tried to sync our on premise the second time, he duplicated our accounts, the problem was he deleted the wrong occurrence.  Undeleted the Account and got back in.